# yeoman build fails - rjs mainConfigFile location

Tags: javascript, requirejs, rjs, yeoman, gruntjs

`yeoman server` works fine, but `yeoman build` looks for my main requirejs file in a strange place and fails:

```
<WARN> Unable to read "scripts/scripts/main.js" file (Error code: ENOENT). Use --force to continue. </WARN>
```

It seems to add that extra scripts/ directory because my baseUrl is ./scripts, but `yeoman server` finds it fine in the correct place.  Here is my setup, it's mostly default stuff:

in index.html:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/vendor/require.js" data-main="scripts/main"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

in Gruntfile.js:

```
rjs: {
  // no minification, is done by the min task
  optimize: 'none',
  baseUrl: './scripts',
  wrap: true
},
```

relevant part of app tree:

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
├── app
│   ├── index.html
│   └── scripts
│       ├── main.coffee
│       ├── vendor
│       │   ├── require.js
|       |   └── all other js library scripts
│       └── all my other scripts
└── package.json
```

If I remove the scripts/ directory from the data-main attribute like this `data-main="main"`, it actually does build without error.  Trying to open the built app in a browser results in a blank page and a console error though, and `yeoman server` fails without finding main.js.  No other tinkering with these parameters that I've tried has given me a successful `yeoman build`.

I hope I'm just missing a small configuration quirk.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was missing a simple `name: 'main'` in the rjs configuration of my Gruntfile, so it should look like this:

```
rjs: {
  // no minification, is done by the min task
  optimize: 'none',
  baseUrl: './scripts',
  wrap: true,
  name: 'main'
},
```

This correctly works with `yeoman server` and `yeoman build`.